# MIPS getting an error when running my code

Tags: mips, mips32, mars-simulator

For our coursework we had to write code in MARS to calculate the memory address of a given coordinate.

```
.globl main

.data

amountOfRows:    .word 16  # The mount of rows of pixels
amountOfColumns: .word 32  # The mount of columns of pixels

promptRows: .asciiz "Please enter the row number:\n"
promptCols: .asciiz "Please enter the column number:\n"

msgShowMemoryAddress: .asciiz "The memory address for the pixel is:\n"
msgErrorValues: .asciiz "The entered value for row/column is invalid, please enter a valid value:\n"

.text
###################################################################################
translate_coordinates:
    sw  $fp, 0($sp) # push old frame pointer (dynamic link)
    move    $fp, $sp    # frame pointer now points to the top of the stack
    subu    $sp, $sp, 20    # allocate 16 bytes on the stack
    sw  $ra, -4($fp)    # store the value of the return address
    sw  $s0, -8($fp)    # save locally used registers
    sw  $s1, -12($fp)
    sw  $s2, -16($fp)

    move $s0, $a0       # $s0 = x coordinate
    move $s1, $a1       # $s1 = y coordinate
    move $s2, $a2       # $s2 = width for calculations
    
    sll $t3, $s1, 5     # shift y left by 5 which is equal to multiplication of 32
    add $t4, $t3, $s0   # (y * 32) + x = index of pixel
    
    sll $t5, $t4, 2     # shift index left by 2 which is equal to multiplication of 4
    
    add $t6, $gp, $t5   # memory address = gp + offset
    
    move    $v0, $t6        # place result in return value location
    
    lw  $s2, -16($fp)   # reset saved register $s2
    lw  $s1, -12($fp)   # reset saved register $s1
    lw  $s0, -8($fp)    # reset saved register $s0
    lw  $ra, -4($fp)    # get return address from frame
    move    $sp, $fp        # get old frame pointer from current fra
    lw  $fp, ($sp)  # restore old frame pointer
    jr  $ra 
    
################################################################################### 
main:

    li $v0, 4       # print string
    la $a0, promptRows  # message to ask the user for the row number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5  # read integer
    syscall    # ask the user for a row number
    move $t0, $v0
    
    li $v0, 4       # print string
    la $a0, promptCols  # message to ask the user for the column number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5  # read integer
    syscall    # ask the user for a column number
    move $t1, $v0
    
    lw $t2, amountOfColumns #load amountOfColumns into $t2
    
    move    $a0, $t0    # Put procedure arguments
    move    $a1, $t1    # Put procedure arguments
    move    $a2, $t2
    jal     translate_coordinates   # Call procedure
    
    move    $t6, $v0    # Get procedure result
        
    move    $a0, $t6
    li      $v0, 1      # syscall code 1 is for print_int
    syscall

exit:

    li $v0, 10  # syscall to end the program
    syscall
```

I wrote this code to calculate the memory address of a pixel but whenever I run it I get this error:

> Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

We had to use a stackframe for this and I'm quite new to that.

Because I'm quite new to it, it might be that I made some mistakes when it comes to that.

Comment: Have you tried single stepping?  You should notice a problem immediately.

Comment: what's that sorry?

Comment: Single step is an approach to debugging.  Most development systems allow running one line at a time and stopping between so you can check the program state is correct after running that last line.  MARS has a built-in debugger.  If you don't know about debugging, now is a great opportunity to develop some skills.

Comment: oh yeah, it happens at the "jr $ra " in the function i made but no clue how to fix it

Comment: Did you notice how it runs the function before it runs `main`?  This is significant (and problematic).

Comment: you're right, give me one moment to check this

Comment: I did it like this because in the example .asm file we got they also put the function before the main

Comment: They might have used a different program which auto-jumps to `main`, this is not a guarantee across all versions of MIPS. Some begin at `.text`, others require a `j main` as the first line, or some header that contains `.word main` at a specific location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MARS starts running the code at the start of `.text`, and since in your code the function comes before `main`, it is running the function without calling it properly.

There are three options:

1. add `j main` immediately after `.text`
2. use MARS option Settings -> Initialize Program Counter to global `main` if defined (off by default)
3. change the order so that `main` comes immediately after `.text`

Comment: Is that just a MARS thing? I've seen some assemblers jump directly to `main` even if there are things between `.text` and `main`

Comment: @puppydrum64, qtspim always looks for `main`, but on MARS it is optional.  Unix linkers probably default to `_start`.

Comment: I've only ever used N64 and PlayStation and I can't remember what they do (it's in a header file that someone else wrote)